# how search duplicate with translate function in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem to adapt my postgresql query to oracle

```
SELECT id, name, firstName
  FROM myschema.individus
  WHERE translate(trim(lower(name)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee') || 
        translate(trim(lower(firstName)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee') in
          (SELECT translate(trim(lower(name)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee') ||
                  translate(trim(lower(firstName)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee')
             FROM myschema.individus
             group by translate(trim(lower(name)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee') ||
                      translate(trim(lower(firstname)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee')
             HAVING COUNT (c) > 1)
  ORDER BY name, firstName
```

For my duplicate search I concatenate name and first name with || operator, and I use translate for accents. but the count function in the HAVING returns 0 so my query returns 0 rows.

If I remove the having statement I have many results.

If I use:

```
having count(translate(trim(lower(name)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee') ||
             translate(trim(lower(Firstname)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee')) > 0
```

no result.

Comment: Try formatting your query.  Hint 1:  it should be on multiple lines.  Hint 2:  if you put four spaces at the beginning of the line, then you get the code formatting.

Comment: What is `c` in the `COUNT(c)` above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest rewriting the query slightly:

```
SELECT id, name, firstName
  FROM myschema.individus
  WHERE translate(trim(lower(name)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee') || 
        translate(trim(lower(firstName)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee') in
          (SELECT translate(trim(lower(name)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee') ||
                  translate(trim(lower(firstName)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee'),
                  COUNT(*) AS cnt
             FROM myschema.individus
             group by translate(trim(lower(name)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee') ||
                      translate(trim(lower(firstname)),'éèêëàâäîïôöùûüçÉÈ','eeeeaaaiioouuucee')
             HAVING cnt > 1)
  ORDER BY name, firstName
```

If it won't accept `HAVING cnt > 1` then use `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.

Comment: with the having count(*) it's ok.
but i can't use the count in the select statement, beacuse i am in the "in" statement, I think i should use exists.
ty.